# How do I format the given sections?

Tags: sectioning

Using the following code, I get a number 1 on top of the listed problems. I was wondering how I can keep the section numbers and listed problems, but get rid of the 1 at the top?

```
\documentclass[16pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1.5in, top=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\title{Homework}
\author{First Name}

\maketitle 
\section{}
\subsection{Problems 3,4,7,8}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to remove the section number from the section, just add a star after the word `section`:

```
\section*{}
```

However, your subsection will then start with a zero, as shown in below.

[image]

If you want to start with the numbering 1.1, you can add the command

```
\stepcounter{section}
```

after the section command. If you want to achieve something different, please update your question.